# trouble with an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have been searching all over the internet, went through stackover flow like crazy and solved half my problem, i am trying to size an iframe when you click a link to load the full size of a page, i have gotten it to work in IE but in FF nothing happens it just stay the same height,

Code that work for IE

```
function calcHeight() {
    var the_height = 0;
    //find the height of the internal page
    if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //test for Firefox/x.x or Firefox x.x (ignoring remaining digits);
        the_height = document.getElementById('class').contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + 140;
    }
    else {
        the_height = document.getElementById('class').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 18;
    }
    document.getElementById('class').height = the_height + "px";
}
```

Iframe code

```
    <iframe src="iframback.html" name="class" id`="class" width="100%" height="auto" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" onload="calcHeight();" allowtransparency='true'></iframe></td>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated i cannot figure this one out!
This is a link to the test page you are suppose to be able to click on 'Ohio Conceal Handgun License (CHL)' and have the code show next to it and have the IFRAME expand down like it does in IE.
Thanks!
http://www.dualactiontactics.com/Update/7/Training.html

Comment: you might want to try to change the iframe height attribute.
document.getElementById('class').setAttribute('height', the_height+'px');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **id`** instead of id in your iframe, first change this

```
<iframe src="iframback.html" name="class" id`="class" width="100%" height="auto" 
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" onload="calcHeight();" allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
```

**id`="class"** to  **id="class"**

and in js change statement

```
document.getElementById('class').height = the_height + "px";
```

to

```
document.getElementById('class').height = the_height;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('class').style.height= the_height + "px";
```

Comment: Thank you! just missed that little bit, thats what happens when you are staring at the code for hours little things slip by.